# Resposta a Perguntas *claramente* fora de escopo

Tags: debate, escopo-do-site

Perguntas como [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59590/criar-virtualhost-no-windows-apache-no-ubuntu) e [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59569/como-instalar-o-unity-3d-5-no-linux-mint) (entre outras) estão, claramente, fora do escopo do SO (existe o ServerFault, e metas parecidos).

A minha pergunta é: O quão correcto é responder a este tipo de pergunta?
Uma vez que se continuar-mos a responder estas perguntas continuaram a aparecer, não será melhor fazer uma "regra de ouro" flaggar as mesmas e avisar o utilizador que existe um sitio específico para esse tipo de perguntas?

Ou estarei eu a ser Draconiano?

Comment: Põe-se para fechar e da-se uma ajuda em comentários... Ou abre-se o SUpt :P

Comment: Eu normalmente flaggo logo como "off-topic" mas tenho notado que há quem responda às perguntas, por isso é que abri um meta ;P

Comment: Relacionado: ["Responder perguntas que foram negativadas, é ruim?"](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1246/215) Não creio que exista um consenso sobre isso, o que eu vejo são pessoas votando pra fechar **e** ajudando o AP como podem, de preferência em comentário mas às vezes como resposta. Não acho correto negativar respostas a perguntas fora do escopo, mas também não as estimulo (votando a favor).

Comment: Je suis SUpt! Free SUpt!

Comment: Apesar do usuário na pergunta da primeira pergunta falar de Windows e Ubuntu, eu notei que assuntos como configuração de servidores é bem aceita aqui por estar muitas vezes ligadas a maioria dos assuntos perguntados (web), veja este exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2211/3635 acho que só a questão das tags linux, windows está desnecessária.

Comment: Eu também estava com essa dúvida mas evitei abrir a dúvida aqui no meta porque vi um monte de questões novas com temas não relacionados a programação onde tem respostas de usuários com alta pontuação (mais de 15 mil). Então eu achei que tinham mudado as regras e estavam permitindo temas não relacionados a programação. Então, afinal, é permitido ou não?  Até então eu vinha marcando para fechar tais questões.

Answer (score 4):

O Stack Overflow em Português não tem nem precisa ter o mesmo escopo do SO, muito menos precisa seguir exatamente pelo mesmo caminho.

O fato de haver um site em Inglês da rede Stack Exchange que atenda o escopo de uma determinada pergunta, não significa que ela não possa ser postada aqui no SOpt.

Aliás, apontar algum site em Inglês como local correto para uma pergunta coloca em cheque a própria existência deste site.

A recomendação da moderação é, por enquanto, aceitar perguntas que seriam de escopo de outros sites mas que tenham a ver com problemas que programadores geralmente enfrentam.

A comunidade espera ter outros sites como o SUpt num futuro não tão distante, mas por enquanto podemos absorver parte das perguntas que outrora seriam exclusivas desses outros sites.

Obviamente isso não significa que devemos aceitar qualquer coisa. Já houve muita discussão sobre isso, mas em geral devemos usar sempre o bom senso e o meta quando necessário, exatamente como você fez. E parabéns por isso! :)

Comment: "A comunidade espera ter outros sites como o SUpt num futuro não tão distante" ai espera? :P

Comment: Corrigindo: "A comunidade **ESPERAVA** ter outros sites como o SUpt num futuro não tão distante".

Comment: @VictorStafusa A posição da SE é que **agora** não dá. Se em um ou dois anos a proposta sair, isso para mim ainda seria um futuro não tão distante.